# JSP Get property | <jsp:getProperty

Tags: java, jsp, tags

I am trying to use the jsp tag as following without jsp:useBean tag.
Value being set in servlet and forwarded to a jsp:

```
request.setAttribute("person", p);
```

In jsp trying to get value:

```
<jsp:getProperty name="person" property="title"/>
```

Sometimes it gets the value and sometimes it throws the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: file:/index.jsp(17,0) 
jsp:getProperty for bean with name 'person'. 
Name was not previously introduced as per JSP.5.3
```

Kindly suggest why the behavior is not predictable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using tomcat6 or later, right?

Try to use `jsp:useBean` tag to reference the bean again before invoke `jsp:getProperty`. It may work:

```
<jsp:useBean id="person" class="xxx.xxx.Person" />
<jsp:getProperty name="person" property="title" />
```

This might be a bug of tomcat. Check this out: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48701

Comment: yes I'm using tomcat 6. it will work definitely, but I'm preparing for exam. and they asked the questions like this without using the jsp:usebean. so, i wanted to make sure it works or not what shall i reply?

Comment: @user3085390: Tell them this is a bug of tomcat, or use an older version of tomcat.

Comment: if i use older version then i don't need to used jsp:usebean tag? i can directly get/set properties of beans available in session/request scopes?

Comment: @user3085390: Yes, but you have to test by yourself. BTW, In the issues page, there is detail description of the bug.